# numpy: any tricks to quickly compute large coocurrence matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, transpose

I have a very large and sparse binary matrix that contains occurrences of certain classes in a set of samples:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> 
>>> type(data)
<class 'scipy.sparse.dok.dok_matrix'>
>>> data.shape
(23571, 139045)
```

So it's `23571` classes and `139045` samples. The matrix is fairly sparse:

```
>>> dataGS.getnnz()/(dataGS.shape[0]*dataGS.shape[1]*1.0)
0.000512511985402024
```

I need to calculate the cooccurrence matrix, the symmetric matrix of size `23571 X 23571` that stores in its `[i,j]`th element the number of times class `i` appeared together with class `j`. I tried doing it by multiplying the data matrix by its transpose:

```
coocc = data.dot(data.T)
```

but ran out of memory. Is there another fast way of constructing the matrix (so, obviously, I am trying to avoid creating a zero `23571 X 23571` matrix and then filling each `[i,j]` position by explicitly looping through every sample and counting pairs)

Comment: If `data` has shape `(23571, 139045)`, then `data.T.dot(data)` has shape `(139045, 139045)`.  Do you have the transpose on the wrong argument?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Excellent point, thx!

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than a dot product, but multiplying DOK matrices is very inefficient. You should convert to CSR or CSC  before computing the dot product ([see here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/sparse.html)).

Comment: Indeed, the trick is to do matrix multiplication, but to do this efficiently you should have a `csr` matrix and not `dok` type. Another problem is that the coocurrence matrix may not be very sparse at all. So with shape `(23571, 23571)` it might have a serious memory requirement. Lastly, maybe you can get away with a smaller `dtype` than you're currently using. Depending on the max `nnz` per row you could use e.g. `uint16`.